# Can't extract some tags from a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I was scraping some data from this URL

```
https://www.degruyter.com/search?query=*&startItem=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=relevance&documentTypeFacet=journal
```

when I try to get the journal names its not giving anything. Some tags giving response, but tags for journal names gives nothing.
div with class name "resultTitle" has journal names but when I try the following in scrapy

`response.css("div.resultTitle").get()` is giving nothing.
I have tried BeautifulSoup also

Comment: you want the part that literally says "Journal" or you want the titles ?

Comment: It seems like the content you want to scrape is modified by JavaScript, but you are getting unmodified raw HTML. See this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50612469/8479597

Comment: To get the content from that site, all you need to do is use `referer` in the headers and send `cookies` while issuing requests.

Comment: @ahmedg, which user's answer from you link?

Comment: @BenchVue answer by John Moutafis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the block contains what you want "resultTitle" was loaded by JS which is [xxxxxxxx-main.js](https://www.degruyter.com/assets/javascripts/b09767817becb9f770e62a7e9f0a6b4d-main.js)

```
...
        a.loginContentPromise.then((()=>{
            const e = document.querySelector("#session-redirect");
            if (e) {
                const t = e.dataset.destination || "/";
                window.location.replace(t)
            }
        }
        )),
...
```

You can find the code block like below if you post your request via "wget" command, instead of using web browser.

```
...
    <main id="main" class='language_en px-0 min-vh-100 container-fluid'>
        
    <div id="session-redirect" data-destination='/search?query=*&amp;startItem=0&amp;pageSize=10&amp;sortBy=relevance&amp;documentTypeFacet=journal'></div>

    </main>
...
```

You can read the "xxxxxxxx-main.js" JS code and implement it.
or just simply use Splash to handle it.

P.S.

```
wget -O search_result.html https://www.degruyter.com/search\?query\=\*\&startItem\=0\&pageSize\=10\&sortBy\=relevance\&documentTypeFacet\=journal
```

Comment: I can see code block after Unminify the main.js but I don't understand, how to block the scrapy by main.js and <div id="session-redirect"> tag? Can you explain more detail?